# "Love to see this happen?" or 'Love to see this happens?" What's the grammar rule behind this?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sense-verbs, infinitive-constructions

It confuses me sometimes. It looks likes the former is far more common. But what's the logic behind that?

Comment: The former is correct, the latter is wrong. I can't explain it in terms of grammatical rules; I'm just a native speaker, not a grammarian.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the lack of a ***subject***, both OP's examples are syntactically fine. Note that

> 1: *He wants to see it **happen***
>    means
>    ***seeing it happen*** is something [that] he wants to do,

...but...

> 2: *He wants to see [that] it **happens***
>    means
>    ***the fact of it it happening*** is something he **wants to ensure** comes to pass

Hence although it's a rather *unlikely* thing to say, if we knew it was from a native speaker we could reasonably interpret OP's *(Love to see it **happens**)* as meaning *I would really like to be tasked with making sure that this takes place*. In practice though, if it was from a learner, it would simply be seen as a *mistake.* He almost certainly intended the *first* meaning above, so it should be *...see it **happen***.

---

The relativizer "that" is *optional* in #2 above, where ***to see*** [that] X happens / takes place / is true means ***to take such actions as are necessary*** to bring about some desired outcome (X occurring, in this case). It's related to the idiomatic usage...

> **see to (someone or something)**
>    *To care for, attend to, or deal with someone or something* [<sub>(thefreedictionary)</sub>](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/see+to+it)

Have a look through results for [*see it doesn't happen*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22see+it+doesn%27t+happen%22) in Google Books for similar examples.

Comment: Agree but would add: He wants to see [that] this happens. So the OP can see it.

Comment: I don't follow you. I *did* add "He wants to see [that] this happens" as my example #2 above. Are you saying OP might be confused because I changed "it" to "this"?

Comment: Yes, I am saying that.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume for the moment that you are assuming both sentences mean the same thing, and want to know why the more common one is correct (for that meaning).

“(I would) love to see this happen”, meaning “I support this happening”, has no *s* on *happen* because in this type of sentence you do not conjugate verbs that are part of the object. Compare these sentences with the same kind of structure:

> I want to see her draw
> *I want to see her draws
>
> I would love to see the dog jump
> *I would love to see the dog jumps
>
> I would love to see him play guitar
> *I would love to see him plays guitar

(The sentences marked with an asterisk are ungrammatical for the same meaning as the preceding sentence.)

---

The reason you will sometimes see sentences of the form “(I would) love to see this happens” is because that has a different meaning: “I would love to take responsibility for making this happen”. A different grammar goes with that meaning.

“To see this done” can mean taking responsibility to do it, but is ambiguous since the same words can have the “I will observe this happening” meaning. They expand differently though: “To see that this is done” and “To see this being done”.

Compare these sentences that all have that “take responsibility to make this happen” meaning, and how their object phrases’ prepositions are different from the examples above:

> I want to see she draws
> *I want to see she draw
>
> I would love to see he plays guitar
> *I would love to see he play guitar

As a final note, it’s grammatical but unusual to see this kind of sentence start with “(I would) love to…”. It’s more usual to see “I will see this happens”, for the same reason that the neutral “I will take responsibility for doing this” is more common that the enthusiastic “I would love to take responsibility for doing this”.

If you are seeing a sentence like “Love to see this happen”, it is far more likely to mean “I strongly support this happening”, and that will usually also be clear from the context.

Comment: Those don't sound right to me without the connective *that*.